# Most efficient way to loop through array elements that need to be processed asynchronously

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

I have 3 async functions. The output of the first is the input of the second. And the output of the first two are the input of the third. Now these 3 will be inside a loop, depending on the length of my array. What is an efficient way to iterate through the array and execute the functions quickly in such a way that the output of the first two functions are still connected to each other? Meaning, they have to have the same length as the array, and their indices are paired with each other. Note that the output does not need to be in order, the *ith* element of first array just need to pair with *ith* element of the second array.

For example:

```
let firstFunctionOutput = [];
let secondFunctionOutput = [];
let thirdFunctionInput = [];
// arr.length = 10,000
// at the end, firstFunctionOutput and secondFunctionOutput should have length = 10,000 as well
for (i < 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  firstFunctionOutput.push(await firstFunction(arr[i]));
  secondFunctionOutput.push(await secondFunction(arr[i], firstFunctionOutput[i]));
  thirdFunctionInput.push(firstFunctionOutput[i], secondFunctionOutput[i]);
}
await thirdFunction(thirdFunctionInput);
```

I just feel like this is too slow because we're iterating and there's too much `await`s. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: Why make `firstFunctionOutput` and `secondFunctionOutput` arrays instead of local variables in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the above code snipped the `thirdFunction` needs all of the outputs from  `firstFunction` and `secondFunction`, but their invocations can be in parallel.

So if each execution of first and second function takes a second the third function could be executed in about 2 seconds

```js
  const firstAndSecond = async (arri) => {
    const output = await firstFunction(arri)
    return [output, await secondFunction(arri, output)]
  }
  thirdFunctionInput = (await Promise.all(arr.map(firstAndSecond))).flat()
  return await thirdFunction(thirdFunctionInput);
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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-1wZg6FIAAPWQk3AbYaFwKgQHoDCjiAA)

Comment: This worked well. Simple and fast. Thank you!